# In Eclipse, how to properly configure sources of Android Library Project?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-library

Consider Android Project A with a dependency on Android Library Project L.

In the default scenario, with the cursor on a method (being invoked in A) but declared in L, clicking F3 will open a read-only source file (showing that method declaration).

Ideally, you want to be able to edit that file and this SO answer suggests how to do this:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7935487/444761

However, this has a nasty side-effect where opening the Call Hierarchy will now show every calling method twice.

What is the correct way to configure the sources?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7935487/444761):

Right click on the non-library project (Project B) and select Build Path:

In the Projects tab, add the library project Project A as a dependency.

In the Order and Exports tab, be sure Project A is given higher precedence than the placeholder/bundle Library Projects.

Thanks to [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7896855/in-eclipse-how-can-i-quickly-access-the-source-of-an-android-library-project/7935487?noredirect=1#comment27381799_7935487):

In the call hierarchy view, click on the downward triangle in the top-right corner, select "Search In", and deselect "Application libraries".