# F3 on Eclipse doesn't go to the class that was selected

Tags: eclipse, adt, android-library

### Background

I have multiple android libraries, each has its own classes.

### The problem

For some reason, for classes that extend from one of those libraries' classes, when I click F3 to go to the class itself, I get an error:

"The Jar of this class file belongs to container 'Android Dependencies' which does not allow modifications to source attachments on its entries"

### What i've tried

I've done some searching of this issue, and found multiple solutions (for example [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2064100/the-jar-of-this-class-file-blongs-to-container-android-2-0-1-which-does-not-allo), [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18942340/the-jar-of-this-class-file-belongs-to-container-android-dependencies-which-doe) and [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10075453/the-jar-of-this-class-file-belongs-to-container-android-dependencies-which-doe)), but none has worked for me:

- clean project
- set the order of the build path to have src at the end, while gen folder is before it.
- update ADT, as it was probably fixed.
- add "Source attachment", but this is impossible for android libraries (blocked for some reason).

### The question

Why does it occur?

How come it's still occuring even on the newest ADT (  i have 22.3.0.v201310242005-887826 )?

Answer (score 0):

Quoting from mik3y [In Eclipse, how can I quickly access the source of an "android library project" from the source of a project that uses it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7896855/in-eclipse-how-can-i-quickly-access-the-source-of-an-android-library-project), which worked for me:

Right click on the non-library project (Project B) and select Build Path:

In the Projects tab, add the library project Project A as a dependency.
In the Order and Exports tab, be sure Project A is given higher precedence than the placeholder/bundle Library Projects.
I had to do both of these steps in order to fix this issue, with ADT15, Eclipse 3.7 and new projects.

EDIT:

[image: Screenshot of project properties]

Comment: can you please show a screenshot of exactly where to put "project A" in the list (the order of where it is placed) ?

Comment: Sorry, can't work out how to upload a screenshot into a comment. I brought my library project above "Android Dependencies" in the "Order and Export" list. That worked for me. (Bearing in mind I also had added the library to the "Projects" tab.) All this was in the project properties for the client project. I'm using ADTv22.0.0. Hope that helps!

Comment: well you can either edit the answer, or add a comment that includes a link to an image hosting website , like the popular "imageshack" website.